# how to solve $x^{113}\equiv 2 \pmod{143}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

I need to solve $x^{113} \equiv 2 \pmod{143}$ 
$$143 = 13 \times 11$$

I know that it equals to $x^{113}\equiv 2 \pmod{13}$ and $x^{113}\equiv 2 \pmod{11}$

By Fermat I got

1)  $x^{5} \equiv 2 \pmod{13}$

2)  $x^{3} \equiv 2 \pmod{11}$

Now I'm stuck..

Comment: If $x^5 \equiv 2 \mod 13$, then $x^{5+(13-1)} \equiv 2 \mod 13$, and $x^{5+2(13-1)} \equiv 2 \mod 13$, etc...

Answer (score 2):

By the *Chinese remainder theorem*, you have to solve first
$$\begin{cases}x^{113}\equiv2\mod13\\x^{113}\equiv2\mod11\end{cases}$$
Now *Little Fermat* says for any $x\not\equiv 0\mod 13\enspace(\text{resp. }11)$, one has $x^{12}\equiv 1\mod 13$, resp. $x^{10}\equiv 1\mod 11$. Hence the system of congruences is equivalent to
$$\begin{cases}x^{113\bmod 12}\equiv x^5\equiv2\mod13,\\x^{113\bmod 10}\equiv x^3\equiv2\mod11.
\end{cases}$$

Let's examine the different possibilities for $x$.

We can eliminate the values $0$ and $1$. Hence,

- modulo $13$, let's draw a table, using the *fast exponentiation algorithm*:
  $$\begin{matrix}
  x& \pm 2&\pm 3&\pm4 &\pm 5 & \pm 6\\
  \hline
  x^2&4&-4&3&-1&-3\\
  x^4&3&3&-4&1&-4\\
  \hline
  x^5&\pm6&\pm6&\mp3&\pm5&\pm 2
  \end{matrix}$$
  Thus the solution is $\;\color{red}{x\equiv6\mod 13}$.
- modulo $11$, we have
  $$\begin{matrix}
  x& \pm 2&\pm 3&\pm4 &\pm 5\\
  \hline
  x^2&4&-2&5&-1\\
  \hline
  x^3&\mp3&\pm5&\mp 2&\mp5
  \end{matrix}$$
  Here the solution is $\;\color{red}{x\equiv-4\mod 11}$.

To solve this system of simultaneous congruences, we need a *Bézout's relation* between $13$ and $11$:
$$6\cdot 11-5\cdot13=1.$$
The solutions of the system of congruences is
$$x\equiv\color{red}{6}\cdot 6\cdot 11-(\color{red}{-4})\cdot5\cdot 13\equiv656\equiv \color{red}{84 \mod 143}.$$

Comment: what can we say about the uniqueness of this solution?

Comment: It is unique modulo $143$.

Comment: how do we get that?

Comment: It's the *Chinese remainder theorem*: $\mathbf Z/11\mathbf Z\times \mathbf Z/13\mathbf Z\simeq \mathbf Z/11\cdot 13\mathbf Z$.

Answer (score 1):

Brute-force approach:

We want to find an $x$ such that $$x^{113} \equiv 2 \pmod{143}$$
We split $\mathbb{Z}_{143}$ into $\mathbb{Z}_{13} \times \mathbb{Z}_{11}$ since $13\cdot 11 = 143$ and $11,13$ are prime. Then, we compute the result of the congruences in $\pmod{13}$ and $\pmod{11}$, that is we solve

$$x^{113} \equiv 2 \pmod{13}$$
$$x^{113} \equiv 2 \pmod{11}$$

On which you already correctly applied Fermat, so you can reduce the exponent always $\pmod{p-1}$ with the prime modulus. Now you solve

$$x^{5} \equiv 2 \pmod{13}$$
$$x^{3} \equiv 2 \pmod{11}$$

By hand, to get

$$x \equiv 6 \pmod{13}$$
$$x \equiv 7 \pmod{11}$$

CRT goes like this: You know two congruences of $x$ in two moduli, that is

$$x \equiv a \pmod{p}$$

$$x \equiv b \pmod{q}$$

Where $p,q$ are relatively prime to each aother. From this, we can deduce the congruence of $x$ modulo $p\cdot q$ with

$$x \equiv a\cdot (q^{-1} \text{ mod }p)\cdot q + b\cdot (p^{-1} \text{ mod } q)\cdot p \pmod{pq}  $$ (Follows from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)

Through @Merlin's answer, we know that in this case

$$x \equiv 6 \pmod{13}$$
$$x \equiv 7 \pmod{11}$$

We calculate the needed inverses by using the extended eucledian algorithm (EEA):

$$13^{-1} \equiv 6 \pmod{11} $$
$$11^{-1} \equiv 6 \pmod{13} $$
We reconstruct $x$:
\begin{align} x &\equiv a\cdot (q^{-1} \text{ mod }p)\cdot q + b\cdot (p^{-1} \text{ mod } q)\cdot p \pmod{pq}\\
&\equiv 6\cdot6\cdot11 + 7\cdot6\cdot 13 \equiv 942\pmod{11\cdot13} \\
&\equiv 84 \pmod{143}
\end{align}
We check that this is indeed a solution by direct computation with wolfram alpha:

[image]

So yes, this checks out.

Comment: I know what to do after I find out x≡6(mod13) and x≡7(mod11), but don't understand how to get that...

Answer (score 0):

$x^5 \equiv 2 (\mod13)$

$x^{12} \equiv 1(\mod 13)$ (Femat's little theorem.)

$5\cdot5\equiv 1 (\mod 12)\\
(2^5)^5 \equiv 2 (\mod 13)\\
(2^5) \equiv 6 (\mod 13)\\
x\equiv 6 (\mod 13)$

Now use the same logic mod 11

$x^{10} \equiv 1(\mod 11)\\
3\cdot7 \equiv 1(\mod 10)\\
(2^7)^3 \equiv 2(\mod 11)\\
(2^7) \equiv 7(\mod 11)\\
7^3 \equiv 2(\mod 11)\\
x\equiv 7(\mod 11)$

Can you get home from here?

Comment: yeah. tnx very much

Answer (score -1):

The first congruence tells you $x \equiv 6 \pmod {13}$ and the second tells you $x \equiv 7 \pmod {11}$, now apply the Chinese remainder theorem to get your answer.

Comment: Can you explain more how you got that??

Comment: Honestly, just by brute force, start at 2 and take 5-th powers, reduce them mod 13 until you get 2. Then repeat for cubes mod 11.

Comment: LOL... I need a formula since I do not have a calculator in the exam :(

Comment: You don't need a calculator to compute 5th powers, and you can always reduce at every step, its fairly quick actually.

Comment: For example, with 6 mod 13, its powers are 6->10->8->9->2, theres no need to ever work with a number greater than the modulus-1 squared.

Comment: We have $(5)(5)+(-1)(12)=1$. So $x^1\equiv(x^5)^5(x^{-12})\equiv 2^5\pmod{13}$. But $2^5\equiv 6\pmod{13}$. Similar idea for the second, using $1=(3)(7)-20$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Did not understand. May you explain more clearly?

Comment: This is only of importance for larger $p$. We want to solve $x^k\equiv a\pmod{p}$, where $\gcd(k,p-1)=1$. By Bezout, there are integers $s, t$ such that $sk+t(p-1)=1$. So $x=x^1=(x^k)^s (x^{p-1})^t\equiv a^s\pmod{p}$. So the solution to the congruence is $a^s$ (or anything equivalent modulo $p$).

Comment: ohhh tnx alot @AndréNicolas

Comment: @TalorT: You are welcome. Useful for large $p$, since extended Euclidean Algorithm, and modular exponentiation, are "fast."